# Codeigniter Grocery Crud update field?

Tags: codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

```
$crud->set_rules('user_password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[konfirmpass]');
$crud->set_rules('konfirmpass', 'Konfirmasi Password', 'trim|required');

$crud->callback_edit_field('user_password',array($this,'_user_edit'));
$crud->callback_add_field('user_password',array($this,'_user_edit'));
```

callback function:

```
function _user_edit(){
    return '<input type="password" name="user_password"/>  Confirmation password* : <input type="password" name="konfirmpass"/>';   
}
```

My question is how to update if only "password" not blank?

Comment: Please tell us *which* CRUD library you are using.

Comment: Also, what CI version is this?

Comment: Thank before, i'm using Grocerycrud, http://www.grocerycrud.com/
And CodeIgniter v 2.0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've installed CI 2.0.3 and GC 1.1.4 to test because at a glance your code looked fine. As it turns out, it is and your code works. I modified the out of the box `employees_management` method in the `examples` controller with GC. Added a user_password column to the database and added your code to the controller.

The code both ensures that the password fields match and that they're not empty when submit.

- Empty results in `"The Password field is required"`
- Mismatched results in `"The Password field does not match the konfirmpass field."`

Perhaps if this isn't working for you, you should post your entire method instead of just the rules and callbacks so we can see if there are any other problems.

[image: Working]

**Edit**

To edit the field, only if the password has been edited you need to add

```
$crud->callback_before_update( array( $this,'update_password' ) );

function update_password( $post ) { 
if( empty( $post['user_password'] ) ) {
    unset($post['user_password'], $post['konfirmpass']);
}

return $post;
}
```

This however may mean that you need to remove the validation for empty password depending on which order the callbacks run (if they're before or after the form validation runs). If they run before the form validation, you'll need to also need to run a call to `callback_before_insert()` and add your validation rules within the two callbacks. Insert obviously will need the `required` rule, and update won't.

**Edit 2, Clarification of Edit 1**

Having looked into it, the validation runs before the callbacks, so you can't set validation rules in the callback functions. To achieve this you'll need to use a function called `getState()` which allows you to add logic based on the action being performed by the CRUD.

In this case, we only want to make the password field `required` when we are *adding* a row, and not required when *updating*.

So in addition to the above callback `update_password()`, you will need to wrap your form validation rules in a state check.

```
if( $crud->getState() == 'insert_validation' ) {
    $crud->set_rules('user_password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[konfirmpass]');
    $crud->set_rules('konfirmpass', 'Konfirmasi Password', 'trim|required');
}
```

This will add the validation options if the CRUD is inserting.

Comment: Thanks `Ben Swinburne`, Yes that i mean. If user add new record so validation rule must working. What i mean exactly is if user `edit record` and leave empty field password so password no need to update and validation rule not required here, but if user edit record and field password not empty i want validation rule work fine. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Hai **Ben Swinburne**, i has to try your suggestion but i'm confuse when i need validation rule and not required?

Comment: Thanks, it work. i'm very glad, not like other user, you try it self :). Maybe I do not really understand so i had to ask.
And finally to update I use this code:

`if( $crud->getState() == 'update_validation' && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) { //Validation run here }`

And use `callback update_password()`.

Thanks **Ben Swinburne**